# How can I get 'max_statement_time' as a global variable in a GCP Cloud Sql mysql 5.6 instance?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

As of mysql version 5.7.8, the variable `max_statement_time` was renamed to `max_execution_time`.  I have an application that checks the database version and sets the correct variable according to that version number.

When I configure my application to use a local mysql installation, everything is fine, but when I configure it to use Google Cloud Sql, it works on 5.7, but fails on 5.6.  The error it gives is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'max_statement_time'￼
```

From a mysql shell I ran `show variables like 'max%time'` and got these results:

- mysql 5.7 via percona: `max_execution_time`
- mysql 5.7 via google `max_execution_time`
- mysql 5.6 via percona `max_statement_time`
- mysql 5.6 via google [empty]

I see that google has documentation about these flags [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#mysql-m) but `max_statement_time` doesn't appear in the list.  Is there something I can do to force that flag to appear so that my application can set it an proceed happily?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud SQL is a Google managed service. You do not have access to change all the mysql flags freely. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags) there is the list of flags that you can see/ modify. If `max_statement_time` is not in that list it you cannot do anything related to it.

My recommendation is to use `max_execution_time` flag instead of `max_statement_time`. As it is mentioned in the documentation:

> For a given flag, Cloud SQL might support a different range than the corresponding MySQL parameter or option.

The flags/ limations are not the same for CloudSQL with a simple MySQL database.